# Save data into new Table Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

im looking to save data from a select query into a new table using snowflake. Usually i use the

`create or replace table as select...`

but this time i cannot get this to work because i am referencing many temp tables, and the queries within these temp tables eg transactions and sales is very complex, so i do not want to write one large query.
Eg the layout of my code is something like this :

```
set start_date = '2021-06-01';

with transactions as ( select * from .....),
with sales as (select * from ....),
with customers as (select * from .....),
with results as (select * from ....),
create or replace table newresults as select * from results
```

please can anyone help me safe the results into a new table newresults?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your structure slightly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE NEWRESULTS AS 
 WITH transactions as (SELECT * FROM ...),
  sales AS (SELECT * FROM ...),
  customers AS (SELECT * FROM ...),
  results AS (SELECT * FROM ...)
SELECT * FROM results;
```